# Weird characters coming being rendered in browser

Tags: html, character-encoding, entities

Heya,
I'm using google api to access calendar data, and when I visit the site (djkstyles.com) I see the following:
http://cl.ly/2y2m3o3D0f0j1z0D0N03

But one some machines, this is what's seen:
http://cl.ly/292g2j3s341O2n3E020Y

It's really strange. The data coming through is consistent from Google; does anyone have any idas on what's up with this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the character-encoding specified explicitly in your Content-Type header?  http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset

Just a double-check.

Comment: good thinking. i've got <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> and it works fine for me on my browser/box, but i'll force it. the problem i have is i can't reproduce it, and thus can't test. also, the characters appear fine elsewhere :S eg. the letter's MAR and APR look fine when written out explicitly; it's just when coming from goog's

Comment: Hmm...do you have any information on the system where you got the weird screenshot from?

Comment: Oh, and just tried going to djkstyles.com using Chrome on Ubuntu and I do see the weird characters.  Do you have access to a VM where you could test this?

Comment: Did the answer below solve the issue for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a little bit more digging, and you're not alone: [Calendar Issues Thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=25ac3d762b235a51).

It seems that adding &hl=en to the end of your URLs should fix this. Like so: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/kbfj3n6iuc3u822d5omj06vt38%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?max-results=5&orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&callback=embedEvents&alt=json-in-script&futureevents=true&hl=en

I tried this and it fixed the raw data for me.